# Locked Screen, Press Ctrl+Alt+Delete to instantly log on

Tags: windows-7, windows-domain, lock-screen, auto-login, ctrl-alt-delete

Local account on a domain joined PC (Windows 7 Professional).  Local account has no password (no worries, it's segregated/secure).

Upon locking the PC, we want to "Press Ctrl+Alt+Delete to log on" screen to appear, but upon pressing the combination, the PC needs to instantly log on to the local account.  Currently after pressing, it just shows the password field and the user simply presses enter (because no password).  Is there a way to skip this extra button press?

I know it's a strange and picky request, but I was wondering if anyone knows whether or not it is possible.